# date_format(from_unixtime()) subselect very slow

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, count

I have the following query I'm trying to use to spit out each day in a date range and show the # of leads, assignments, & returns:

```
select 
date_format(from_unixtime(date_created), '%m/%d/%Y') as date_format, 
(select count(distinct(id_lead)) from lead_history where (date_format(from_unixtime(date_created), '%m/%d/%Y') = date_format) and (id_vertical in (2)) and (id_website in (3,8))) as leads,
(select count(id) from assignments where deleted=0 and (date_format(from_unixtime(date_assigned), '%m/%d/%Y') = date_format) and (id_vertical in (2)) and (id_website in (3,8))) as assignments,
(select count(id) from assignments where deleted=1 and (date_format(from_unixtime(date_deleted), '%m/%d/%Y') = date_format) and (id_vertical in (2)) and (id_website in (3,8))) as returns 
from lead_history 
where date_created between 1509494400 and 1512086399 
group by date_format
```

The `date_created`, `date_assigned`, and `date_deleted` fields are integers representing timestamps. `id`, `id_lead`, `id_vertical` and `id_website` are already indexed.

Would adding indexes to `date_created`, `date_assigned`, `date_deleted`, and `deleted` help make this faster? The issue I'm having is that it is very slow, and I'm not sure an index will help when using `date_format(from_unixtime(...`

Here is the `EXPLAIN`:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Need `INDEX(date_created)` for the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code you could rewrite the query as  ..

```
  select 
      date_format(from_unixtime(date_created), '%m/%d/%Y') as date_format
      , count(distinct(h.id_lead) as leads
      , sum(case a.deleted = 1 then 1 else 0 end) assignments
      , sum(case b.deleted = 0 then 1 else 0 end) returns
  from lead_history  h 
  inner join assignments on  a a.date_assigned = h.date_created 
        and a.id_vertical = 2 
        and id_website in (3,8))
  inner join assignments on  b b.deleted = h.date_created 
        and a.id_vertical = 2 
        and id_website in (3,8))
  where date_created between 1509494400 and 1512086399 
  group by date_format
```

anyway  you shold avoid unuseful () and nested (),  avoid unuseful conversion between  date  and use join instead of subselect  .. or at least reduce similar sabuselect using case

PS for what concern the index remember that the use of conversion on a column value invalid the use of related the index ..

Comment: But the counts in my query aren't using date_created, they're using date_assigned and date_deleted.

Comment: answer  updated ..  but the concept and the suggestion remain the same

Comment: this doesn't work because `date_assigned` is a unix timestamp. therefore `date_assigned` might not equal `date_created`.

Comment: Need `INDEX(id_vertical, date_assigned, id_website)` and ditto for `deleted`.